# Receives a dynamic link and navigates to the desired page Xamarin.Form but Xamarin.Android is not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, dynamic-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I want to write code that receives a dynamic link and navigates to the desired page.

So I wrote the below, and both iOS and Android receive it.

Xamarin.Form code

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {

        public MainPage()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, TestModel>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "dynamicLink", getURl);
        }

      

        private  void getURl(App sourece, TestModel model)
        {   
            Console.WriteLine(model.page);
            Navigation.PushAsync(model.page);
        }
    }
```

Xamarin.Android code

```
class OnSuccessListner : Java.Lang.Object, IOnSuccessListener
    {
        void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            var link = result.JavaCast<PendingDynamicLinkData>();
            Android.Net.Uri deeplink = null;
            if (link != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("received");
                deeplink = link.Link;
                Console.WriteLine($"{deeplink}");
                var Model = new TestModel();
                if (deeplink.Path == "/Test")
                {   

                   switch(deeplink.GetQueryParameter("ModelName"))
                    {
                        case "Test1":
                            Model = new TestModel { page = new Test1() };
                            break;
                        case "Test2":
                            Model = new TestModel { page = new Test2() };
                            break;
                        default:
                            Console.WriteLine("Not Value");
                            break;
                    }
                }

                MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "dynamicLink", Model);
            }
        }

    }
```

Xamarin.iOS

```
public override bool ContinueUserActivity(UIApplication application, NSUserActivity userActivity, UIApplicationRestorationHandler completionHandler)
        {   

            return DynamicLinks.SharedInstance.HandleUniversalLink(userActivity.WebPageUrl, (dynamicLink, error) => {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(error.LocalizedDescription);
                    return;
                }
                var compoents = new NSUrlComponents(dynamicLink.Url, false);
                var queryitems = compoents.QueryItems;
                var Model = new TestModel();
                if(compoents.Path == "/Test")
                {
                    var queryitem = (from item in queryitems
                                where item.Name == "ModelName"
                                select item).First();
                    if(queryitem != null)
                    {
                        switch (queryitem.Value)
                        {
                            case "Test1":
                                Model = new TestModel { page = new Test1() };
                                break;
                            case "Test2":
                                Model = new TestModel { page = new Test2() };
                                break;
                            default:
                                Console.WriteLine("Not Value");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }

                Console.WriteLine(dynamicLink);

                MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "dynamicLink", Model);
                // Handle Universal Link
            });
```

However, on Android, there is a problem that MessagingCenter listens twice and an error of "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Page must not already have a parent.'
"

So I modified the method. I change my Moethod like this.

```
private async void getURl(App sourece, TestModel model)
        {   
           
            if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{model.page} - iOS");
                await Navigation.PushAsync(model.page);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{model.page} - Android");
                await Navigation.PushAsync(model.page);
                MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<App, TestModel >((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "dynamicLink");
                
            }
            
        }
```

MessagingCenter received it once, but it doesn't move to the page.

May I know what the problem is!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. check that link.

```
void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var link = result.JavaCast<PendingDynamicLinkData>();
    Android.Net.Uri deeplink = null;
    if (link != null)
    {
        ...
        //MessagingCenter.Send((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "dynamicLink", Model);
        App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(Model.page);
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/533837/receives-a-dynamic-link-and-navigates-to-the-desir.html

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.